# Assign 1 GB to each executor in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a following code :-

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Data")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40,192.168.0.106,192.168.0.113")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "10")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
  .set("spark.cores.max", "10")
  .set("spark.driver.cores", "3")
```

I have 4 node cluster with 3 core each. Trying to execute a job to run on 9 executor in cluster with 1GB RAM each as mentioned in spark.executor.memory When I check spark UI it shows that 1 GB is ocuupied on each node but

[image]

The Screenshot shows that I have 10 cores and 1 GB is assigned to each core but at below it is seen that 1 GB is assigned per node. But when I run my application each executor shows 336 MB , as we can see in this image below :-

[image]

Need to understand how is this working and if it is consuming 3 GB on each node then why assigned just 336 MB for each executor ?

Thanks,

Comment: If you post links, at least post them using the built-in image uploader. If the links you just gave ever go down, this post will be rendered useless and lost to history

Comment: @LonelyNeuron - Thank you for correcting I didn't knew this feature. Updated my code now as per your suggestion.

Comment: You have 13 executors in the picture whereas in conf you have only mentioned 10. Also, the one you see in the picture, is the storage memory. The memory value that you assign to executors is divided into different parts, some for computation, some for storing the cached data.

Comment: @philantrovert - my bad.. sorry , I was testing so took screenshot of different cases. I got your point that assigned memory is further divided into different parts that means I need to increase my memory to give more for storage memory. Thanks,